# No module named requests /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/

Tags: python, pip, python-requests

I'm trying to install some modules through pip using a `requirements.txt` file.

The file has:

```
behave
requests
```

When I run the install requests doesn't get installed into site-packages:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
```

My error is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

I think something is up with my Python and pip installations:

```
python --version = 3.7.3
```

`pip -V = pip 19.1.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-19.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip (python 2.7)` --Not sure how to change this

```
~/.bash_profile
alias python='python3'
alais pip='pip3'

which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: Have you tried `pip3 install requests`?

Comment: Yes I have, when I run the behave command I get the same error

Comment: You may have more than one Python 3.x interpreter. Try `python3 -m pip install requests behave` to make sure that you are using the correct interpreter.

Comment: what's your console output when you type `which -a python`, `which -a pip`

Comment: /usr/bin/python and /usr/local/bin/pip

Comment: when I do python3 -m behave it works, not sure why I need to explicitly state python3 as python --version returns 3.7.3

Comment: By default you installed Python 2.7 requests.

Comment: I ended up changing the pip path to pip3 >> /usr/local/bin/pip. I then run python -m pip install -r requirements.txt and it works now. Thanks all.